# Не могу понять в чем проблема перезапуска бота через systemd?

Tags: python, telebot, vds

В интернете определенно много статей о решении этой проблемы, но ни одна из них мне не помогает. Столкнулся с такой  проблемой, что получаю ошибку `«status = 203 / EXEC»` при запуске бота на сервере. Для примера мне пока что нужно запустить от `root`.

Файл `bot.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mybot - Telegram bot
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/myname/bot/  
ExecStart=/usr/lib/python3 /home/myname/bot/bot_example.py
RestartSec=60
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Не уверен, что правильно указал путь к `ExecStart` к интерпретатору, но, как указывают в примерах - стоит писать: `/usr/bin/python3`, но у меня не существует такого пути, по крайней мере `../python3` зато существует путь `/usr/lib/python3`, который я указал уже в исполняемом скрипте (`chmod +x script.py`) первой линией Шебанга - `#!/usr/lib/python3`, но я все равно получаю эту ошибку.
Укажите, пожалуйста, почему я не могу запустить свой скрипт на сервере?

OS - Linux Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: Во-первых, Ubuntu 18.06 не существует. Во-вторых, если у вас отсутствует /usr/bin/python3 значит вы забыли установить питон, а присутствие /usr/lib/python3 здесь ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal, прошу прощения за неправильно указанную версию - подправил. А питон установлен 3.6. Во всяком случае напрямую `python3 script.py` запускается, а вот с `systemd` возникают проблемы.

Comment: Какой путь пишет `which python3` команда?

Comment: @andreymal, странно, указывает `/usr/bin/python3`. Сейчас еще раз попробую заменить в `bot.service`

Comment: После обновления файла не забывайте делать systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: @andreymal, да, наконец-то с этим порядок, наверно из-за того что забывал `daemon-reload`:) Но сейчас получаю `status=1FAILURE`. Я так понимаю - ошибка уже в самом скрипте? Напрямую, если запускать - проблем нет.

Comment: `journalctl -u bot` чтение логов (`--since=-1h` за последний час)

Comment: @andreymal, посмотрел - указывает, что `/usr/lib/python3 : Permission denied`. Буду разбираться, как предоставить доступ.

Comment: Вероятно вы прочитали старые логи, читайте новые логи внизу

Comment: @andreymal, да, вы правы, так и есть - смотрел старые логи. Ошибка в том, что нет библиотеки `telebot`. Наверно неправильно указываю путь к интерпретатору, так как здесь на vds есть и `3.6`, `3,7`и `3.8`

Comment: @andreymal, подскажите пожалуйста, как указать правильный путь к интерпретатору, который я использую?  Если ввести в терминале `python3` то я запускаю python 3.6.9. `pip3 install pytelegrambotapi` укажет, что библиотека `telebot`уже установлена, но, вероятно, когда хочу создать в systemd службу по запуску бота - то указывается другой интерпретатор.

Comment: Как минимум убедитесь, что служба и pip3 запускается от одного и того же пользователя; если вы установили telebot пользователю myname (или кто там у вас), а запускаете бота от root, от telebot конечно не увидится (да и вообще, запускать бота от root — крайне сомнительная идея)

Comment: @andreymal, да, все заработало, спасибо огромное. А от рута мне нужно было только проверить systemd, позже создам нового пользователя. Чуть позже добавлю ответ на собственный вопрос :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдельное спасибо @andreymal, который помог разобраться в этом.

Крайне НЕ рекомендуется запускать бота от имени `root`.

Чтобы быстро решить вашу проблему:

1.Отредактировать ранее созданный файл `bot.service` (или любое другое имя), в директории `/etc/systemd/system`, в котором нужно обязательно правильно указать пользователя, от которого будет запускаться служба.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mybot - Telegram bot
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=yourname #ваш пользователь
WorkingDirectory=/home/yourname/bot/  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/yourname/bot/bot_example.py #1 путь к интерпретатору, 2 путь к вашему скрипту
RestartSec=60
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Указать линию Шебанга в своем скрипте 1 строкой. Это путь к вашему интерпретатору.

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

Чтобы в этом удостовериться - введите в консоль следующую команду:

`which python3`

3. При каждом внесении в `bot.service` не забывать вводить команду - `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Если что-то идет не так, или бот не запустился, смотрим логи (где будет указана ваша ошибка) такой командой:

`journalctl -u bot --since=-1h`.

В этом журнале я смог обнаружить свою ошибку - что неправильно указан путь к интерпретатору и что не установлен пакет `telebot` - пакет не был установлен из-за того, что служба `systemd`и `pip3` запускались не от одного и того же пользователя.